# Encontrar objetos por um valor de variável com FindObjectsOfType

Tags: unity3d

O comando `FindObjectsOfType` pode encontrar objetos por um tipo específico.

Gostaria de saber se ele pode encontrar objetos por um valor de variável.

Por exemplo: Encontre objetos que tem a variável *x* com valor igual a 10.

Comment: Dúvido que haja algum método já establecido para fazer o que deseja, o melhor será criar um ciclo de objectos e verificar se existe o valor da variável que deseja.

Comment: Já agora qual é seria a necessidade de pesquisar um objecto deste modo. O que pretende fazer?